# CSS Box-Shadow Not Working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

How would I get this to work in IE?

```
.fancy {
     border: 1px solid black;
     margin: 10px;
     box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #cccccc;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #cccccc;
     -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #cccccc;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Any version. Mainly 7,8, or 9.

Comment: IE what? 9 is quite a bit different that 6.

Comment: That works in IE9. Did you bother testing?

Comment: What version of IE are you using? It works on IE9 & Chrome in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/g65kN/

Comment: @Daniel: They show the border in my browser... I think this problem is specific to your browser.

Comment: @Daniel: Posted an answer. Try my suggestion and let me know if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Daniel: Correction. The link you provided does not work in IE9, which means that there is something on your page that's affecting it. It works on IE9 in my Fiddle, so I suspect it might have something to do with the compatibility setting in the meta section.

Answer (score 56):

On your site, this CSS rule is preventing `box-shadow` from working in IE9:

```
table, table td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

**See:** [box-shadow on IE9 doesn't render using correct CSS, works on Firefox, Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617455/issue-with-box-shadow-on-ie9/5617540#5617540)

> You must add `border-collapse: separate;` to the element that `box-shadow`
>   is not working on.

So, this should fix the problem for you:

```
.fancy {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: And now IE10 also suffers from this.  Pity Microsoft removed conditional comments.

Comment: This is sooo unreasonable ! great find :D

Comment: The issue once reported in https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/770636/ie10-box-shadow-bug-not-rendered-on-tables and set Closed as Won't Fix, since IE is discontinued and replaced with Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 7):

box-shadow is supported from IE9 onwards.

There are plenty of sites out there describing how to do this for older IEs. One of them is: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/

Also check out: http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

My **personal** opinion in general on making older browsers do things they actually cannot is this:
**Avoid it**. Instead apply the principles of [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). Also explain to your client that solving problems of *outdated*, non standard browsers with non standard solution, is very time consuming and probably not worth the effort.

Comment: This is where I got the code from. I saw that adding the method he used can't be applied to a single class.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with single class?

Comment: IE 8 is indeed a "non-standard" browser, but it's not particularly "outdated" yet, and especially not in a way that most clients will accept. You really do need to support the current version (*n*) and version *n–1*.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm in agreement with you. I get carried away sometimes :-) Most clients will require IE7 support and in certain regions even IE6.

Answer (score 5):

It works fine in IE 9.

Earlier versions doesn't support `box-shadow`, but you can use a filter:

```
zoom: 1;
filter:
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#eeeeee, Strength=15, Direction=90),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#eeeeee, Strength=15, Direction=180);
```

Read: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. Do you have compatibility mode enabled perhaps?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: You only need the filter to support older versions, IE 11 supports `box-shadow`.

Comment: Yes, I have determined that box-shadow does work in IE11 (it works in IE11 on my Meteor app), but it doesn't work on my Sharepoint page. That's the rub for me. Maybe it's the "meta XA-UA-Compatible" or whatever line that I see in my markup (which I did not add myself, and don't know where it stems from)...?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: There is mainly two reasons for adding that meta tag; either to tell IE that compatibility mode is not needed, or to tell IE to render the page as an older version. If it's the first case, then you could change it to specify "edge" (search for exact syntax) instead of a specific version, that would keep if from render it as the wrong version.

Comment: @Guffa: But since this is coming from a master page "up the chain of command" how it is set is how the powers-that-be want it to be set. We have to support many older versions of IE (unfortunately); and IE seems to play best with Sharepoint (also unfortunately, albeit understandably).

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: Then you are stuck writing code for the version of IE that the meta tag tells IE to pretend to be... If the version number is too low there are some things that you simply won't be able to use at all.

Comment: @Guffa: "Dang it!" <= Kip Dynamite.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use http://css3pie.com/

> PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the
>   most useful CSS3 decoration features.

Answer (score 2):

By default IE was setting up IE10 Compatibility mode which should be replaced with IE 9 using meta-tag. So, whenever it will be running on other browsers then it will use the CSS that will be compatible with IE9. As in IE10 Compatibility mode box-shadow CSS property has been removed from the library

We can use meta-tag in head just to change the document compatibility level:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,IE=9" />
```

Above tag is showing that make this document compatible with IE8 and IE9 for browsers other than IE8 and IE9 switch CSS level to IE9.

Answer (score 1):

From google: `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#cccccc', Direction=135, Strength=3);`

Probably not exactly as you want it, but fiddle around with it or look into `DXImageTransform` some more.

Answer (score 1):

On IE you need to use filter for that effect.

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
zoom: 1;
```

Comment: For me (IE11), this makes the entire image one giant shadow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is specific to your browser, because it works for me in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g65kN) on both IE9 & Chrome. The link you provided works in Chrome, but not in IE9. This would indicate that the issue is specific to your implementation.

I would check to make sure that compatibility mode is disabled, and also make sure you don't have any settings enabled that would interfere with CSS. I would also suggest testing this in multiple browsers and using process of elimination to determine why it isn't working.

**EDIT**

I was just looking at your markup. Try removing this line and see if it makes a difference:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: I would like to try that; I do see that line in my "View Source" but don't know how it gets there. I'm not explicitly adding it, that's for sure. Perhaps it's on one of the master pages that this page derives from/uses.

Answer (score 0):

It's already 2018, happens the same with IE11.
Sometimes the **box-shadow** doesn't work, but sometimes it does.

I tried this with IE11 and IE10:
Try changing the **display** of the element where you want to add the shadow (usually *"display: block"* works fine):

```
.fancy {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: block;` to CSS class works for me in **IE11**...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that IE doesn't seem to like hex colors with 8 digits (the last two were for the alpha channel).  I solved the problem by switching from hex colors to rgba() colors.

I discovered this by accident and I'm surprised I haven't seen it documented anywhere yet!

Answer (score 0):

The probably most elegant and functionable way to set IE-specific styling today are media-queries. Despite they're not the most beautiful, it work's reliable without making use of filters or even JS.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
/* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
}
```

For more Details see: https://philipnewcomer.net/2014/04/target-internet-explorer-10-11-css/