# CSS animation function doesn't work in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a calling animation using JS and CSS. I tested in most of the browser and it is working fine. But unfortunately, the shadow effect not supporting IE.

I tested in IE 11. I added additional CSS to work on all browser. But still, `animation` function is not supporting in IE and I couldn't fix the issue. Please run the below code and help me.

```js
var setRinging = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".ringing").addClass("-ringing");
  }, 600);
};

setRinging();
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.h-list,
.actions {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-item-style: none;
}

.h-list>li,
.actions>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.call {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #0b5d4c;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 1s, background-color 600ms, opacity 600ms;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.ringing {
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #1ab394;
}


/* inner */

.head {
  font-size: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.details {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 0px 5px;
}

.details2 {
  color: #d6fff6;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.actions {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.action {
  padding: 0 8px 0 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.action>a {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1ab393;
}

.action>a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}


/* animation */

.-fadeout {
  -webkit-filter: blur(6px);
  filter: blur(6px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.-drop {
  -webkit-filter: blur(6px);
  filter: blur(6px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20%) rotateX(20deg);
  transform: translateY(20%) rotateX(20deg);
}

.-flip {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipback {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.-ringing {
  -webkit-animation: _ringing 800ms infinite;
  animation: _ringing 800ms infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forward;
  animation-fill-mode: forward;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes _ringing {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(6px, 0px);
    transform: translate(6px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(2deg);
    transform: rotateZ(2deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-6px, 0px);
    transform: translate(-6px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-2deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-2deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 0px);
    transform: translate(3px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(1deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px);
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-1deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 0px);
    transform: translate(2px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(1deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes _ringing {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(6px, 0px);
    transform: translate(6px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(2deg);
    transform: rotateZ(2deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-6px, 0px);
    transform: translate(-6px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-2deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-2deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 0px);
    transform: translate(3px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(1deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px);
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-1deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 0px);
    transform: translate(2px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(1deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}


/* eq */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  opacity: .2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sound:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.fa-ban {
  color: tomato;
}

.head {
  height: 46px;
}

#eq {
  width: 220px;
  height: 46px;
}

.call-animation {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-animation: play 2s ease infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: play 2s ease infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: play 2s ease infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: play 2s ease infinite;
  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  min-height: 209px;
  background-color: #1ab393;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  15% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  15% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  15% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
}

@keyframes play {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  15% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="call-animation">
    <div class="call ringing">
      <div class="head"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></div>
      <div class="details">+912 345 678 912 is calling...</div>
      <div class="details2">User Name</div>
      <ul class="actions">
        <li class="action"><a id="accept" href="#">View Details</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vibrate effects is working in IE but background shadow animation is not working in IE. Please check the image.
[image]

Comment: @xmastertje I updated an image. Please check whether the background shadow animation works on IE? I just tested again and it's not working in IE 11.

Comment: I can confirm the animation is bugged in IE11

Comment: @acmsohail hmm you are right

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949396/css-box-shadow-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: @xmastertje I tried most of them. But still the same :( Any other solutions? Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @acmsohail I also tried some but it didn't work either...

Comment: The `box-shadow` seems to be supported on IE11, have you tried chopping down your code to see what CSS property is causing the `box-shadow` to stop showing? I would assume it has something to do with the `@keyframes`, `animation` or even `transform`. I tried checking if any of the properties are not supported, but they seem they are.

Comment: @xmastertje it's working fine after I add this code. `box-shadow: none` thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set box-shadow: none initially . Complete code given below

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.h-list,
.actions {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-item-style: none;
}

.h-list>li,
.actions>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.call {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #0b5d4c;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 1s, background-color 600ms, opacity 600ms;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.ringing {
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #1ab394;
}


/* inner */

.head {
  font-size: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.details {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 0px 5px;
}

.details2 {
  color: #d6fff6;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.actions {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.action {
  padding: 0 8px 0 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.action>a {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1ab393;
}

.action>a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}


/* animation */

.-fadeout {
  -webkit-filter: blur(6px);
  filter: blur(6px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.-drop {
  -webkit-filter: blur(6px);
  filter: blur(6px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20%) rotateX(20deg);
  transform: translateY(20%) rotateX(20deg);
}

.-flip {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipback {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.-ringing {
  -webkit-animation: _ringing 800ms infinite;
  animation: _ringing 800ms infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forward;
  animation-fill-mode: forward;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes _ringing {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(6px, 0px);
    transform: translate(6px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(2deg);
    transform: rotateZ(2deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-6px, 0px);
    transform: translate(-6px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-2deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-2deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 0px);
    transform: translate(3px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(1deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px);
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-1deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 0px);
    transform: translate(2px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(1deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes _ringing {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(6px, 0px);
    transform: translate(6px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(2deg);
    transform: rotateZ(2deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-6px, 0px);
    transform: translate(-6px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-2deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-2deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 0px);
    transform: translate(3px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(1deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px);
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-1deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 0px);
    transform: translate(2px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(1deg);
    transform: rotateZ(1deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}


/* eq */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  opacity: .2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sound:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.fa-ban {
  color: tomato;
}

.head {
  height: 46px;
}

#eq {
  width: 220px;
  height: 46px;
}

.call-animation {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-animation: play 2s ease infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: play 2s ease infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: play 2s ease infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: play 2s ease infinite;
  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  min-height: 209px;
  background-color: #1ab393;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow:none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
 15% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  15% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  15% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
}

@keyframes play {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  15% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 20px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.4), 0 0 0 30px rgba(26, 179, 147, 0.2);
  }
}
    </style>
</head>


<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="call-animation">
    <div class="call ringing">
      <div class="head"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></div>
      <div class="details">+912 345 678 912 is calling...</div>
      <div class="details2">User Name</div>
      <ul class="actions">
        <li class="action"><a id="accept" href="#">View Details</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var setRinging = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".ringing").addClass("-ringing");
  }, 600);
};

setRinging();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```