# Is it possible to render a box-shadow in internet explorer while using Perch CMS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, box-shadow, perch

I am using

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

and

```
header {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -18px 99px -53px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -18px 99px -53px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
box-shadow: inset 0px -18px 99px -53px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

[Click here to see the staging site](http://darbyfox.studiolynch.com)

This is not displaying in every version of Internet Explorer including IE 11 Metro. I'm testing through browserstack.com and do not have access to an actual copy of IE. Thanks!

**Update:**
The original question was addressing the fact that my box-shadow css was not rendering in any version of IE.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617455/box-shadow-on-ie9-doesnt-render-using-correct-css-works-on-firefox-chrome) gave me the clue that

```
<!doctype html>
```

needs to be on the very first line of the page. The problem is that I'm using Perch CMS which requires a line of php on the very first line of the page. [See documentation.](http://docs.grabaperch.com/docs/adding-perch/) The question now becomes: Is it possible to render a box shadow in internet explorer while using Perch CMS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [box-shadow on IE9 doesn't render using correct CSS, works on Firefox, Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617455/box-shadow-on-ie9-doesnt-render-using-correct-css-works-on-firefox-chrome)

Comment: Please define "not working". Are you getting unexpected size or position? You aren't getting the shadow at all? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Wanna try this. Please put your doctype in line 2 or after the closing php tag on a new line. So when the php in the page is rendered in a browser your doctype should now be the first line.